# Having a proxy machine with Windows KDNET kernel debugging?

Tags: windows, kernel, remote, debug

I'm using KDNET to debug a Windows kernel driver on a second laptop via Ethernet cable. It works by directly plugging the Ethernet cable from the host to the target laptop. The [process is described in MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-kernel-mode-debugging-in-windbg--cdb--or-ntsd).

Is it possible to set it up with a *proxy* machine (or whatever you want to name it) so that I can debug from my debugging machine without being near the target laptop?

Some visualisation for how it's currently set up:

```
Working & Debugging Machine (Host)
              ^
          (ethernet)
              v
    Target Machine (Target)
```

This is how it should be:

```
Debugging Machine (WinDbg is running here)
                  ^
              (wireless)
                  v
      Proxy/Working Machine (Host)
                  ^
              (ethernet)
                  v
        Target Machine (Target)
```

Answer (score 0):

WinDbg supports this kind of "proxy", it is called a *debugging server* (see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/remote-debugging-using-windbg)). You can run WinDbg on your proxy machine in server mode by specifying the `-server` command line option:

```
windbg -server tcp:port=5005 -k net:port=50000,key=<YOUR_KEY>
```

and then connect to it from the laptop:

```
windbg -remote tcp:Port=5005,Server=DebuggingMachine
```

where `DebuggingMachine` is an address/hostname of your proxy machine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).